# Can we integrate Pentaho and Google Visualization API or to flex?

Tags: apache-flex, google-visualization, pentaho, mondrian, rolap

I have developed one Mondrian schema and cube. I have deployed schema file in Pentaho BI server. I would like to know is it possible to connect these Pentaho schemas and UI technologies like Google Visualization API or Adobe Flex?

While searching for solution I came to know about OLAP4J and icCube, out of which I think OLAP4J is very old project and its not really active project. icCube looks good but it works with its own server, it cannot be integrated with Pentaho BI server.

Right now I am thinking about Google Visualization API and Adobe Flex. Or, is there any other option?
Where can I get more information about it?

Comment: olap4j is most definately not an old project, it's used as a building block in lots of other projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pentaho added a new client-side vizualization API in V4.0. This API is compatible with the Google Visualization API.

The API code is in biserver/pentaho-solutions/system/common-ui/resources/web/vizapi
* VizController is a generic controller that pages can use to work with visualizations that implement the API
* DataTable.js is an open source DataTable/DataView implementation

There is a test harness in biserver/pentaho-solutions/system/common-ui/resources/web/test/vizharness.html
You can access the test harness with this URL: http://localhost:8080/pentaho/content/common-ui/resources/web/test/vizharness.html

This API can be used in conjunction with the Data Access API that let's you retrieve data via a javascript API. You could use the Data Access API to retrieve data, and either Flex or the Visualization API to display the data.

Pentaho is extending/improving this API in V4.5. Feedback on the API is welcomed.

James Dixon, Lord of the 1's and 0's, Pentaho

Comment: Is this client-side vizualization API in V4.0 available in community edition or only in Enterprise edition?